# Invoking :make -j2" fail and undefined reference to 'libusb

Tags: catkin-make, raspberrypi, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am working on hector_slam with sick_tim, sensor tim571 on a raspberry pi 3 B+.  i have this error when catkin_make. After checking i realise my /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/ file is empty. There is no libary files.  How do i solve this?

command:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
 
git clone https://github.com/uos/sick_tim.git
 
cd ~/catkin_ws/
 
catkin_make
```

Error:

```
 [ 38%] Linking CXX executable /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310_1130000m01
[ 41%] Linking CXX executable /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_mrs1000
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_config_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_set_debug'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_close'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_open'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_unref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_ref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_config_descriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_tim310_1130000m01.dir/build.make:141: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310_1130000m01' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_tim310_1130000m01] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1715: recipe for target 'sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_tim310_1130000m01.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_tim310_1130000m01.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_config_descriptor'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_set_debug'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_close'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_init'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_open'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_release_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_unref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_ref_device'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_bulk_transfer'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_claim_interface'
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsick_tim_3xx.so: undefined reference to `libusb_free_config_descriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_mrs1000.dir/build.make:219: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_mrs1000' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sick_tim/sick_mrs1000] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1518: recipe for target 'sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_mrs1000.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sick_tim/CMakeFiles/sick_mrs1000.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307104/invoking-:make--j2%22-fail-and-undefined-reference-to-%27libusb/) by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-10-30**:
have you installed libusb-1.0-0-dev? This is required for this package.

**Comment by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) on 2018-10-30**:
yes i installed i just make a very stupid mistake :"""D i didnt clean the build space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem. Anyone that face similar problems may want to  check out my [Solution](https://github.com/uos/sick_tim/issues/71#issuecomment-434196437) ^_^

---

Originally posted by [rui](https://answers.ros.org/users/38136/rui/) with karma: 28 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-09**:
Instead of leaving your solution on an external website, can you please update your answer with the relevant information so that the answer will be self-contained